# excel filter function, multiple criteria OR

Tags: excel, filter, boolean, criteria

excel filter function:

=filter(range1, ((tbl1[acct]=$b$1)*(tbl1[ticker]=$c$1)))

multiple criteria, as constructed, it says true for crit1 AND crit1. how can i make the criteria "OR"? meaning criteria true from first crit, or second crit, or both? thx

Comment: Your formula works for me. Use an asterisk for AND and + for OR, as Harun said, but make up your mind if you want both AND and OR because that can't be done. Your formula returns an error if no matches are found. Embed it in IFERROR() for that case. There might also be an error in your `Range1` or in the purpose to which you apply the filtered result. I tested `=SUM(FILTER(Table1[Amt],(Table1[Acct]=$F$1)*(Table1[Ticker]=$G$1)))` and `=SUM(FILTER(Table1[Amt],(Table1[Acct]=$F$1)+(Table1[Ticker]=$G$1)))`. Both work.

Comment: Got it TY for the responses

Answer (score 0):

For `OR` logic use `+` plus operator like-

```
=Filter(range1, ((tbl1[acct]=$b$1)+(tbl1[ticker]=$c$1)))
```

Comment: Hmmm when I enter values for both criteria it’s not filtering to just those values that have both